# Support for wildcard queries, n-gram tokenization in Amazon Kendra

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kendra

1. Does Kendra support wildcard queries? (eg: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html)
2. Does it have n-gram tokenizer to implement incremental search/search-as-you-type feature?

Answer (score 0):

1. Kendra does not support wildcard queries.
2. Kendra supports query suggestions. More details - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kendra/latest/dg/query-suggestions.html#no-suggestions

Comment: Kendra suggests queries based on popular queries in the query logs/query history and not based on the lexicon of the search engine (i.e index). Want to implement the latter.